# Cmake: How to build custom compiler binary and then use it for some targets?

Tags: c++, cmake

I need to build a custom C++ compiler binary and then use it for some targets in the project.

What is the best way to do it in modern CMake?

I set a dependency from the compiler target, and it works as expected, but then what, use 'generator expressions' to get the compiler target binary name?

`set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ...)` -- either it doesn't understand generator expressions or I misuse it somehow.

Is there a way to set the compiler only for specific targets? As I understand, `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER)` works for current directory and its children.

Comment: Are you trying to build a compiler and then use the compiler to do subsequent compiles in the same project?

Comment: How is the custom C++ compiler compiled? I'm afraid if it's C++ code itself, things can become complicated.

Comment: I would use `execute_process` to launch a separate `cmake` build job for the compiler. And then another one to launch your main `cmake`, passing along any required arguments and a toolchainfile (possibly generated, since you now know the binary directory of the first cmake).

Comment: @Gardener, yes, build a compiler (actually just a command line shell) and then do subsequent compiles in the same project, but for different targets.

Comment: @Scheff, the compiler itself is a just a command line shell, not a real compiler, so it's not so complex)

Comment: Hmm. Not sure, if I got you right. We use custom tools to generate C++ sources, which are then compiled into DLLs (e.g. own grammar files -> flex sources -> C++ -> .obj). If that's what you're looking for, I could have a look into our `CMakeLists.txt`s. It was a bit tricky to get the dependencies right but is working reliable on our side (with VS2013).

Comment: @Scheff, yes, exactly, build a custom tool and then use it in the same build process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a toolchain file, which are made to specify cross compilers.

Here's an example I took from the documentation:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /home/devel/rasp-pi-rootfs)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /home/devel/stage)

set(tools /home/devel/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

This is okay since it's in a toolchain file. CMake is made to properly handle toolchain files.

You use it by specifying it in the command line arguments:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=your_toolchain.cmake
```

Comment: Thank you. A toolchain -- is it global for the whole build process? Can I use something only for specific targets? Like set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ...) only for some targets.

Comment: @Hexagonal I don't know much about cross compiling. Maybe you'll notice something you like in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html).

Answer (score 0):

I made an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a sample application (`App/app.cc`) with non-C++ source code (`App/text.txt`) which has to be compiled via intermediate C++ sources.

The sample directory tree:

```
└┬─ ./
 ├─── CMakeLists.txt
 ├─┬─ App/
 │ ├─── CMakeLists.txt
 │ ├─── app.cc
 │ └─── text.txt
 └─┬─ Tool/
   ├─── CMakeLists.txt
   └─── tool.cc
```

The file `./CMakeLists.txt` is the main project file (provides the solution for VisualStudio):

```
project(App)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_subdirectory(App)
add_subdirectory(Tool)
```

The source code `./Tool/tool.cc` for a build-tool to generate a C++ source and a header out of a text file:

```
// a sample tool converting a text file to a c++ source

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 3) {
    std::cerr <<
      "ERROR in tool: Missing arguments!\n"
      "\n"
      "Usage:\n"
      "tool TXT_FILE CC_FILE\n";
    return -1;
  }
  std::ifstream fIn(argv[1]);
  if (!fIn.good()) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open '" << argv[1] << "' for reading!\n";
    return -1;
  }
  const std::string fileH = std::string(argv[2]) + ".h";
  std::ofstream fOutH(fileH);
  if (!fOutH.good()) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open '" << fileH << "' for writing!\n";
    return -1;
  }
  const std::string fileCC = std::string(argv[2]) + ".cc";
  std::ofstream fOutCC(fileCC);
  if (!fOutCC.good()) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open '" << fileCC << "' for writing!\n";
    return -1;
  }
  fOutCC << "#include \"" << fileH << "\"\n\n";
  for (std::string buffer; std::getline(fIn, buffer);) {
    const size_t i = buffer.find('=');
    if (i < buffer.size()) {
      fOutH << "extern const char *const " << buffer.substr(0, i) << ";\n";
      fOutCC << "const char *const " << buffer.substr(0, i)
        << " = \"" << buffer.substr(i + 1) << "\";\n";
    }
  }
  fOutH.close();
  if (!fOutH.good()) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't complete writing of '" << fileH << "'!\n";
    return -1;
  }
  fOutCC.close();
  if (!fOutCC.good()) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't complete writing of '" << fileCC << "'!\n";
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The file `./Tool/CMakeLists.txt` to build the tool:

```
project(Tool)

add_executable(tool
  tool.cc)

set_property(TARGET tool
  PROPERTY FOLDER "Tools")
```

The file `./App/text.txt` – a text file which has to be converted to generated sources `text.cc` and `text.h`:

```
text1=Hello World.
text2=Text built with tool -> VC++
```

The source `./App/app.cc` where `text.h` is included:

```
// a sample app using an indirect built source file

#include <iostream>

#include "text.h"

int main()
{
  std::cout << "text1: '" << text1 << "'\n";
  std::cout << "text2: '" << text2 << "'\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Finally, the `./App/CMakeLists.txt` which introduces the custom build step:

```
# custom build step
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT
    text.cc text.h
  COMMAND
    tool "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/text.txt" text
  MAIN_DEPENDENCY
    text.txt
  DEPENDS
    tool
  COMMENT
    "generate C++ sources from text"
  VERBATIM)

# regular C++ build
add_executable(app
  app.cc          # regular source files
  text.cc text.h) # intermediate source files

# add build dir for project to include directories
include_directories(app 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>)
```

Having `DEPENDS tool` in `add_custom_command` and the `OUTPUT` of `add_custom_command` in `add_executable` grants that:

1. `test.txt` is listed as source in the VS-project of `app`
2. VS-project `tool` is included into VS-solution `App`
3. `tool` is compiled and linked, and then used to convert `test.txt` to `test.h` and `test.cc` before `app` is compiled and linked (successfully).

The generated intermediate sources appear in the build directory (don't pollute the source directory). Hence, the build directory has to be set as include path as well. Otherwise, the `#include "text.h"` (in `app.cc`) wouldn't work.

Comment: Scheff, thank you for the thorough example! A couple of questions: (1) In COMMAND it just uses the name of target "tool", not a path to the binary, how it finds where the actual binary is located? (2) Is there a way to use it for all files with some extension? In the example, you need to specify the custom command for every such "test.txt".